# I have an array and I want to check if all the values from array are equal to what I want using edittext

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Here is an example of my array

`List<Integer> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();`

all values inside this array are:

`sampleList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Basically I'm using `for` to loop each values from this array

```
for (int i = 0; i < sampleList.size(); i++) {
     int to = sampleList.get(i);
     if (norooms == to) { //norooms = 1
         //display a toast 
      }
  }
```

I want to check if position 0-5 are all equal to 1 but I cant achieve it. Any help

Comment: what `moroons` in supposed to be?

Comment: do you want to check FOR all the elements if they are equal to norooms, or do you want to check IF all the elements are equal to norooms? it's just a word, but a big difference.

Comment: that's the no of rooms that the users want. Retrieved using the shared preferences

Comment: @Stultuske I want to check for all the elements if they are equal to norooms

Comment: how can there be a number of room if there are no rooms?

Comment: @fantaghirocco that's not the whole code just a sample

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
int editTextValue = 3; // Your edit text value
boolean isEqual = true;//Flag to check if all the values are equal or not.
 for (int i=0; i<sampleList.size(); i++){
        if (sampleList.get(i) != editTextValue){
            isEqual = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
```

Then check the condition of **isEqual** after the loop is over and handle accordingly.

Comment: this will no longer check for all the values

Comment: He needs to know if all the values are equal to `EditText` value. So even if one of the value is different, it is going to solve his purpose.

Comment: no, I asked it in a comment, he wants the comparison done for all the elements

Comment: @Joshua this will answer whether all the values are identical or not, but it won't check it for each unique element. This also means, if your requirements state you need to check how many are different, you won't be able to find it with this.

Comment: @Stultuske True. it will only check if the values are identical. I answered as per the question raised by the post owner. Let him try and see if his problem is getting resolved or not.

Comment: the problem with the question is that it's open for interpretation. In the comments he said he wanted to check them all seperately. so, dealers choice :)
otherwise, a shorter way to handle it would be: sort the array, check the first (and, if need be the last) value(s), and you would know in two comparisons instead of having to iterate over the entire array

Comment: That is another way to do. :-). It is much faster way.

Comment: I can't try it right now, yup @Stultuske that's is what I want to check it seperately

Comment: @Joshua if you want to check them seperately, this code won't help, since it checks up until a not-matching one is found

Comment: @Stultuske yup tried it doesn't work any ideas how to?

Comment: @Joshua I added an answer, you can check that

Answer (score 0):

```
Arraylist<String> matchedValues = new Arraylist<>();
String editTextValue = edittext.getText();
String arrayValue;
boolean isEqual ;
boolean isEveryElementPresent = false;
for (int i = 0 ; i < sampleList.size() ; i++){
    arrayValue = sampleList.get(i);
    if(arrayValue.equals(editTextValue)){
        isEqual = true;
        matchedValues.add(arrayValue);
    }else{
        isEqual =false;
    }
}

if(matchedValues.size() == sampleList.size()){
        isEveryElementPresent = true;
}
```

Comment: I can spot one issue with efficience, and one major issue with your code, why it won't work. what is the relation with the result of your code, and the value of the last element of the array?

Comment: @Stultuske Can you please tell me the issue briefly??

Comment: you will only get the result for the final element of the array. if that is equal to the value you want to check it with, it returns 'true'. you don't store the information about previous elements, you overwrite it each time. This way, you won't even know if there were other values in the array, unless the last element differs.

Comment: Store the indices whenever you put isEqual to true

Comment: @VidorVistrom did It, Thanks for you help.

Comment: @BhavikParmar how does your improvement help? the only difference is that you'll be able to check how many elements were equal to the original text

Comment: @Stultuske yeah you were right, that is why i added one for loop at the end to check it for all the values, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public Check {
  int value;
  int index;
  boolean match;
  // constructor, setters and getters
}
```

For about all the information you want:

```
public List<Check> checkValues(List<Integer> originalList, Integer testValue) {
  List<Check> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for ( int i = 0; i< originalList.size(); i++ ) {
    result.add(new Check(i, originalList.get(i), originalList.get(i) == testValue);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This is 'a way' to do it. You'll have information on how many matches there were, which other values there were and on which index in your List they were found.

Comment: Do I really need to create a Model class?

Comment: you "need to" do nothing, but depending on what you want as result, or what, where and how you want to use from the results, you might. it depends on your usecase, if you just need to print a value, no, you don't need it at all, if you want the information for later processing, you'll need a way to store it

Comment: @Joshua did this enough to help you further, or did you need something else?

Comment: I find it complicated for me as a beginner if I use a model class

Comment: Any other way to do this simplier??

Comment: @nani10 it all depends on your requirements (which we don't know). You can always store the data as instance variables/static variables in your class itself, but then you shouldn't forget to "clean" them when needed

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Java Streams, check out more on: [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Basically turns the list into a stream of elements and then you can process the data.

```
//To get only the elements equal to 1
sampleList.stream()
  .filter((num) -> num == 1);

//to get a list of booleans whose value depends on the element being equal to 1.
List<Boolean> listBooleans = sampleList.stream()
  .map((num) -> num == 1)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

- filter uses a predicate to determine if the element matches a certain condition, in this case number == 1.
- map transforms the stream of Integers into a Stream of booleans where the result is number == 1.
- collect terminates the stream, with Collectors.toList transforms it into a List.

Hope this helps.